# How to open an external app in Cordova/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app. In my app I want to have a button that will open another app. I tested the hyper link in safari and the link opens the app correctly, but when I click the button inside my Ionic app, it's not working. The Xcode reports

> Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use cordova-plugin-whitelist ?

Comment: @Yuyang Is it a web app that you are trying to open from mobile app?

Comment: @Gandhi, it is an IOS native app. I have found the workaround, which is to add the cordova-plugin-InAppBrowser

Comment: @YuyangShen Posted the detail answer. Accept if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use externally hosted web application in your cordova application, check out [cordova-hosted-webapp-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-hostedwebapp). The plugin enables using content hosted in a web site inside a Cordova application by providing a manifest that describes the site. Also it lets you use the features of Cordova plugins too.

But if you are trying to just invoke the external web URL from your cordova app, you can make use of [cordova-InAppBrowser-Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) which opens the web URL inside the app itself.

You can also check out [cordova-themeable-browser-plugin](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) which is almost similar to InApp browser plugin and provides more control on the browser elements available in the UI. Hope it helps